# prevent method execution on design time using attributes

Tags: c#, methods, attributes

Is there a way to prevent a method from execution if it is in design time or the method can only be executed at runtime.

I got this problem while creating a custom control because there is a method call in the constructor that will only work at runtime.

now at design time while designing the form and use that control, then the form will generate the error.
now i tried this at the constructor of the user control

```
    public ctrl_information()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)) return;
        SomeMethod();
        //Other code
    }
```

what i want to achieve now is something like this.

```
[ExecuteOnlyAtRuntime]
public void SomeMethod()
{
     //Code here
}
```

Then call it like this.

```
public ctrl_information()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)) return; -- removing this line
        SomeMethod();
    }
```

Is it possible?

Please shed some light on this.

Thank you

Comment: Create a 2nd constructor for the class that contains a parameter(s).  Pass either LicenseManager.UsageMode or LicenseUsageMode.DesignTime as parameter.

Comment: Are you using winform ?

Comment: Yes, I am using winforms

Comment: any reason why it is voted down?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that someMethod is in a control, you may use Component.DesignMode.

So a simple approach could be

```
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (this.DesignMode == false)
        {
            //Code here
        }           
    }
```

Incase the Some function is not in a control, you may implement something like this -

```
public void SomeFunciton()
    {
        if(VisualStudioUtility.IsRunningInVisualStudio == false)
        {

        }
    }



 static class VisualStudioUtility
{
    private const string IDE_EXE = "devenv.exe";

    public static bool IsRunningInVisualStudio
    {
        get
        {
            return Environment.CommandLine.Contains(IDE_EXE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this can be done, but the problem is if the method is outside the control

Comment: ah ok... I'll implement another example for such a case .